Union of lists with original order
I would like to combine a few lists such that the resulting list follows the order of the original lists, which will have disjoint elements, but their order is compatible.
input = {{a,C,2},{b,C},{a,b},{b,2,z},{2}}
output = {a,b,C,2,z}

I thought of //Flatten//DeleteDuplicates//SortBy[#,orderBasedOnInput]&  without success.
Any comment would be much appreciated.

Explain "but their order is compatible."

Is that ordering pre-defined somewhere? I.e. can we use it to sort the final output or do we need to infer the ordering from the inputs?

That was exactly the problem. I do not have access to the original sorting function... (that was applied over each list before: that is what I meant by compatible)

Well, we can define/discover an ordering as pairs like this: Catenate[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ input]

After having a look at @andre314 answer, "compatible order" apparently meant that the graph resulting from connecting subsequent elements of each list is an AcyclicGraphQ

Here is an approach that uses Graph and TopologicalSort :
input = {{a, C, 2}, {b, C}, {a, b}, {b, 2, z}, {2}}

 (Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ input) //
    Flatten[#, 1] & //
   (Apply[Rule, #] & /@ # &) //
  Graph[#, VertexLabels -> Automatic] & //
 TopologicalSort


{a, b, C, 2, z}

Here is what happening when the inputs are not consistent :
input = {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}};

 Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ input //
    Flatten[#, 1] & //
   (Apply[Rule, #] & /@ # &) //
  Graph[#, VertexLabels -> Automatic] & //
 TopologicalSort



Super interesting. This works always and the theory behind is beautiful. Thank you so much

Assuming you have a consistent and unambiguously defined order throughout your lists, you can use use Sort with a custom ordering function. This ordering function looks through your initial lists and for each pair of elements determine their correct order from a list in which both elements are present.
lists = {{a, C, 2}, {b, C}, {a, b}, {b, 2, z}, {2}};

ordering[lists_][x_, y_] := 
 FirstCase[lists, 
  list_ /; ContainsAll[list, {x, y}] :> 
   First@Sign[FirstPosition[list, y] - FirstPosition[list, x]], False]

Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[lists]], ordering[lists]]
(* {a, b, C, 2, z} *)


Thanks! Adding the list {1,2} at the end returns {a, b, C, 2, z, 1}. In the flattened list, the last two elements are z and 1, and they do not appear together in any list.

But your solution indeed works great for the minimal example I posted, so I will accept it

@Albercocm, sorry, I didn't properly account for such cases. Now I've added that ordering returns False if the two elements are not found together, so now the result is {1, a, b, z, C, 2}.
